# Joining rigs deletes parts

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm trying to give a humanoid character bird feet. I'm using rigify to make the armature. Every time I try to frankenstein the bird feet bones onto the rest of the body, it deletes the character's fingers (or vice versa depending on which armature I select first). Why does this happen, and how can I get around this?

(I have already generated the bird and humanoid rigs and deleted the parts I don't need. The finger deletion also happened before rig generation, however.)

model with armature:[image]

Separate armatures:
[image]

Joined (fingers missing):
[image]

Comment: Without any images or a Blend file it's impossible to guess. See [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) and you can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: I think your really have to share the .blend, as simplified as you can make it, on https://blend-exchange.com/ , for this to be answerable. Please edit and illustrate.. as it stands, this question is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear', because, although we want to help, we don't have enough to go on.

Comment: I'm having some issues with the .blend uploader. I'll get that up as soon as I can but I've added screenshots now.

Comment: My recommendation: learn how to use Rigify correctly. Or bang your head against the wall when your frankenstein attempts fail. The choice is yours. Plug to my free Rigify course on YT :) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJt1GvL-Fcxy-fPgEFG-1fLp